# Question regarding my source control setup - should i use branches or multiple repos?

Tags: version-control

Sorry if this isnt the correct forum to post a source control related question, but i wasn't sure where else to ask.

So im setting up a git repository for my team - developers & artists. Gitlab is our host and sourcetree is our client.

How is it possible to set it up in such a way that our artists arnt required to pull all the developer commits, and the developer's arnt required to pull all the artist commits. Because this is currently what happens when we are all working on the master branch.

Would the best way to achieve this be different branches(master, dev, art), set up multiple repositories or is there a better way?

Thanks ~Scott

Answer (score 0):

If the code which the developers and artists are contributing is ultimately being used in the same software product, then you probably want to be using a single Git repo.  As for avoiding integrating changes from the other party, you really can't completely avoid it.

A simple suggestion is along the lines of what you already mentioned, namely having a separate `dev` and `art` branch.  During each sprint cycle, developers and artists would contribute to their separate branches.  At the end of the sprint, someone familiar with Git and the entire codebase, such as a dev ops person or maybe a developer, could merge both branches back to `master`.  Then, he could spawn new feature branches for the developers and artists, for the next sprint.  This approach could largely shield each party from having to worry about the work the other is doing.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the reply. So regarding the overlap of artists and developers. The atrists and developers wont be working in any of the same software, our work flow is an artists develops an asset in their 3d modeling software, once completed they hand it off to the developer who integrates it into the project. This would likely be done by saying xx completed asset is in xx location in our repo, the developer would then proceed to pull from the "art" branch(or separate repo depending on what i decide to do), integrate it into the "dev" branch and push to the dev branch.

Comment: But ive been messing around with creating branches, but switching between branches keeps removing files from other branches locally (which is kinda annoying). and the master will need to be constantly merged to be kept upto date with all the branches.

Comment: Let's say the developers are building Android apps, and the artists create icons and other graphics for those apps.  In this situation, even though you view the two as separate, they are really connected, because the app has embedded in it artwork and image files from the artists.  So, I would recommend using a single repo in this case.

Comment: Ok, But how would i set up the branches in such a way that our developers dont need to pull all the changes to the .psd files, they only want changes to the .png files? But i would still like the developers to be able to pull .psd files if they need to make a quick edit etc, and visa versa. Thanks

Comment: Ok i will keep working on these branches and see if i can get it to work how i want. Thanks ~Scott

Comment: I don't know what else to say.  In a clean setup, I was thinking that maybe the devs would not have to interact with the artists latest work, at least not during the current sprint.  This would allow for a clean separation.